# Ruby Array conversion best way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way to achieve the following, I have following array of actions under ABC

ABC:-

```
ABC:Actions,
ABC:Actions:ADD-DATA,
ABC:Actions:TRANSFER-DATA,
ABC:Actions:EXPORT,
ABC:Actions:PRINT,
ABC:Detail,
ABC:Detail:OVERVIEW,
ABC:Detail:PRODUCT-DETAIL,
ABC:Detail:EVENT-LOG,
ABC:Detail:ORDERS
```

I want to format this as:

`ABC =>{Actions=> [ADD-DATA,TRANSFER-DATA,EXPORT,PRINT], Detail => [Overview, Product-detail, event-log,orders]}`

Comment: You have two arrays? One with the `Actions` and another one with `Detail` or it's all in the same array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a ton of ways to do it but here's one:

```
a = ["ABC:Actions",
"ABC:Actions:ADD-DATA",
"ABC:Actions:TRANSFER-DATA",
"ABC:Actions:EXPORT",
"ABC:Actions:PRINT",
"ABC:Detail",
"ABC:Detail:OVERVIEW",
"ABC:Detail:PRODUCT-DETAIL",
"ABC:Detail:EVENT-LOG",
"ABC:Detail:ORDERS"]

a.map { |action| action.split(":") }.inject({}) do |m, s|
  m[s.at(0)] ||= {}
  m[s.at(0)][s.at(1)] ||= [] if s.at(1)
  m[s.at(0)][s.at(1)] << s.at(2) if s.at(2)
  m
end
```

The `map` call returns an array where each of the strings in the original array have been split into an array of elements that were separated by `:`. For example `[["ABC","Actions","ADD-DATA"] ... ]`

The `inject` call then builds up a hash by going through each of these "split" arrays. It creates a mapping for the first element, if one doesn't already exist, to an empty hash, e.g. `"ABC" => {}`. Then it creates a mapping in that hash for the second element, if one doesn't already exist, to an empty array, e.g. `"ABC" => { "Detail" => [] }`. Then it adds the third element to that array to give something like `"ABC" => { "Detail" => ["OVERVIEW"] }`. Then it goes onto the next "split" array and adds that to the hash too in the same way.

Comment: Added some explanation. Bit hard to do it succinctly though - or at least a bit hard for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I will do this as below :

```
a = ["ABC:Actions",
"ABC:Actions:ADD-DATA",
"ABC:Actions:TRANSFER-DATA",
"ABC:Actions:EXPORT",
"ABC:Actions:PRINT",
"ABC:Detail",
"ABC:Detail:OVERVIEW",
"ABC:Detail:PRODUCT-DETAIL",
"ABC:Detail:EVENT-LOG",
"ABC:Detail:ORDERS"]

m = a.map{|i| i.split(":")[1..-1]}
# => [["Actions"],
#     ["Actions", "ADD-DATA"],
#     ["Actions", "TRANSFER-DATA"],
#     ["Actions", "EXPORT"],
#     ["Actions", "PRINT"],
#     ["Detail"],
#     ["Detail", "OVERVIEW"],
#     ["Detail", "PRODUCT-DETAIL"],
#     ["Detail", "EVENT-LOG"],
#     ["Detail", "ORDERS"]]

m.each_with_object(Hash.new([])){|(i,j),ob| ob[i] = ob[i] + [j] unless j.nil? }
# => {"Actions"=>["ADD-DATA", "TRANSFER-DATA", "EXPORT", "PRINT"],
#     "Detail"=>["OVERVIEW", "PRODUCT-DETAIL", "EVENT-LOG", "ORDERS"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was just interesting to do it with group_by :)

```
a = ['ABC:Actions',
'ABC:Actions:ADD-DATA',
'ABC:Actions:TRANSFER-DATA',
'ABC:Actions:EXPORT',
'ABC:Actions:PRINT',
'ABC:Detail',
'ABC:Detail:OVERVIEW',
'ABC:Detail:PRODUCT-DETAIL',
'ABC:Detail:EVENT-LOG',
'ABC:Detail:ORDERS']

result = a.map { |action| action.split(":") }.group_by(&:shift)
result.each do |k1,v1|
  result[k1] = v1.group_by(&:shift)
  result[k1].each { |k2,v2| result[k1][k2] = v2.flatten }
end 

p result 

{"ABC"=>{"Actions"=>["ADD-DATA", "TRANSFER-DATA", "EXPORT", "PRINT"], "Detail"=>["OVERVIEW", "PRODUCT-DETAIL", "EVENT-LOG", "ORDERS"]}}
```