# Finding the index of a particular element in an array with duplicated elements

Tags: ruby, arrays

Let's say I have the following array:

```
array = ["a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b"]
```

I want to find the index of the first "b" in the array. What is the best way of doing it?

Comment: What is the reason for down voting?

Comment: Because you could have found this by reading the docs, or via Google, I'd imagine.

Comment: I did read some doc on google. The scenario I am asking is a tricky one. Most of the examples online are without duplicated elements which is why I am posting my question here.

Comment: It's not tricky at all, `index` will find the first "b" without trouble: `'aabb'.index('b') => 2`.

Comment: Sorry I still couldn't accept this question as a duplicate. Existing questions are always under the case WITHOUT duplicated elements. It is only not tricky if you already know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-index)
 *for first occurrence* and [`Array#rindex`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-rindex) *for last occurrence of an element*.

```
array = ["a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b"]
array.index("b") # => 6
array.rindex("b") # => 11
```

Comment: +1 I guess it's hard to beat that simplicity :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson could you look into my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174644/ruby-array-conversion-best-way/17176704#17176704. I am thinking it can be made more simplistic,but I can't. so any help or advice from you.

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know it will actually return the index of the first found element using .index(), most of the examples online are without duplicated elements. Thanks!